# Create a new file with same perms and owner as an existing file

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, solaris-10

What is the best way to create a new, empty file that has the same ownership and perms as an existing file for a Solaris /bin/sh shell script?

This is for rotating a log file away for compression and dump storage.

At the moment I am using:

```
mv log log_ts && cp -p log_ts log && cp /dev/null log
```

Is there a better way to do it?

**Update:** Unfortunately this is on a conservatively built live Sol10 server and no gnu fileutils are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this in GNU, I guess it would work on Solaris too:

```
touch new_file && chmod --reference=old_file new_file
```

Comment: I guess you'd want to `chown --reference=old_file new_file` as well in order to meet the OP's requirement?

Comment: Thanks Sahand and Celada for the suggestions but unfortunately this server cannot have any GNU fileutils installed. (I've updated my question with this fact)

Answer (score 1):

You will need do something like this:

```
PERM=`ls -l $EXISTING | cut -d" " -f1 | cut -c2- `
PERMU=`echo $PERM |cut -c1-3 | sed s/-//g`
PERMG=`echo $PERM |cut -c4-6 | sed s/-//g`
PERMO=`echo $PERM |cut -c7-9 | sed s/-//g`
chmod u="$PERMU" $TARGET
chmod g="$PERMG" $TARGET
chmod o="$PERMO" $TARGET
```

Naturally this is for Solaris.